Ellipse: $x$ corresponding to minimum distance between $(x,y)$ and one focus
Consider an ellipse with foci in $(-c, 0)$ and $(c, 0)$, where $a$ is the length of the semimajor axis. Consider a point $(x,y)$ belonging to the ellipse. The point verifies the equation:
$$\sqrt{(x - c)^2 + y^2} = 2a - \sqrt{(x + c)^2 + y^2}$$
The Left Hand Side is also the distance $d_1$ between the point $(x,y)$ and the focus $(c, 0)$. How to obtain the $x$ value which minimizes such a distance?
It should be $x = a$. I tried to use the Right Hand Side as a function and to compute is partial derivative with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ 2a - \sqrt{(x + c)^2 + y^2} \right] = - \frac{x + c}{\sqrt{(x + c)^2 + y^2}}$$
If this is algebraically correct, there are two issues:

it does not depend on $a$;
the solution $x = -c$ is not even a point of the ellipse.

Is it possible to obtain the abscissa of the ellipse point which minimizes $d_1$ from the above equation? If yes, how? If no, which is the correct procedure?

are you looking for any method to prove that x=a is the shortest distance or are you looking specifically for an answer obtained using the derivative you did? because there are much easier ways to show it without touching calculus

In the LHS substitute $y^2$ taken from the equation of the ellipse, to get a function of $x$ only.
